# Why this error occurs in my code for Lax Wendroff?

Tags: pde, python, advection

I want to implement the Lax Wendroff method for a non linear advection equation which is

$$\frac{u_{i}^{n+1}-u_{i}^{n}}{t} + \frac{f(u_{i+1}^{n})-f(u_{i-1}^{n}) }{2h} -\frac{t}{2h} \left( F_{i+1/2}^{n} \frac{f(u_{i+1}^{n})-f(u_{i})^{n}}{h}) - F_{i-1/2}^{n} \frac{f(u_{i}^{n})-f(u_{i-1}^{n})}{h} \right)=0$$

for the problem:$$u_{t} +u u_{x} = 0$$
for
$t \in  (0,1)$,

$x \in (0,1)$

$$u(0,x) = \exp(-10(4x-1)^{2})$$

```
import numpy as np
def NLLaxWendroff(Nx,Nt,t_end):
    Nx = Nx+1                         # Number of grid points
    xmax = 1.                         # Domain limit to the right
    xmin = 0.                         # Domain limit to the left
    h = (xmax-xmin)/(Nx-1)           # Mesh size
    x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,h)       # Discretized mesh

    U =  np.exp(-10*(4*x-1)**2)       # Initial solution
                                                                 


    dt = 1.0/Nt                        # Time step
    t = 0.                            # Initial time

   # upwind scheme (7.18) from Dr.Georgoulis Notes after rearrangement (solving for u_{i}^{n+1})
    while (t <= t_end):
        t = t+dt
        v = t/(2*h)
        a = (t**2)/(2*h)
        Un = U
        Um = np.roll(Un,1)
        Up = np.roll(Un,-1)
        F_plus  = 0.5 * (Up + Un)
        F_minus = 0.5 * (Un + Um)       
        U =  Un - v * (Um-Up) + a * (F_plus  * Un-Um - F_minus *Um-Up)
      


    plt.plot(x,U)
    plt.title('t='+str(round(t_end,2)),fontsize=16)
    plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('u',fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
NLLaxWendroff(100,100,0.6)
```

But the following error occurs:

````
<ipython-input-55-f6e78f745ea8>:24: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  U =  Un - (v * (Up-Um)) + a * (  (F_plus  * (Un-Um)) - (F_minus *(Up-Um))   )
<ipython-input-55-f6e78f745ea8>:24: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  U =  Un - (v * (Up-Um)) + a * (  (F_plus  * (Un-Um)) - (F_minus *(Up-Um))   )
<ipython-input-55-f6e78f745ea8>:22: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  F_plus  = 1/2 * (Un - Um)
<ipython-input-55-f6e78f745ea8>:23: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  F_minus = 1/2 * (Un - Up)
<ipython-input-55-f6e78f745ea8>:24: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  U =  Un - (v * (Up-Um)) + a * (  (F_plus  * (Un-Um)) - (F_minus *(Up-Um))   )

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few issues with your implmentation:

- you should replace $t$ by $dt$ in your discrete equation (both in your code and in the question), otherwise it makes no sense !
- the second part of your equation (with $a$) seems incomplete or wrong, and there's a mix between $F$ and $f$. Moreover, you flux evaluation is wrong: `Fplus` should read `0.5*Up**2` for example.
- there are also missing brackets around `Un-Um` and `Um-Up` in the computation of U.

I've implemented the Lax-Wendroff scheme based on http://folk.ntnu.no/leifh/teaching/tkt4140/._main075.html and it seems to work fine.

The following code compares your implementation with the various fixes, and the new one. Both work and give identical results.

````py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nx=100;Nt=100;t_end=2.0
nChoice = 1

### LAX-WENDROFF SCHEME with periodic BCs
Nx = Nx+1                         # Number of grid points
xmax = 1.                         # Domain limit to the right
xmin = 0.                         # Domain limit to the left
h = (xmax-xmin)/(Nx-1)           # Mesh size
x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,h)       # Discretized mesh
U =  np.exp(-10*(4*x-1)**2)       # Initial solution
dt = 1.0/Nt                        # Time step
t = 0.                            # Initial time

aplus, aminus, Fplus, Fminus, Fn = (np.zeros(Nx-1) for i in range(5))
nsteps = 0
while (t <= t_end):
    if np.any(np.isnan(U)):
      raise Exception('NaNs detected --> exit')
      
    if nChoice==0: # your implementation
        v = dt/(2*h)
        a = (dt**2)/(2*h**2)
        Un = U
        Um = np.roll(Un,1)
        Up = np.roll(Un,-1)
        # F_plus  = 0.5 * (Up + Un)
        # F_minus = 0.5 * (Un + Um)
        F_plus = 0.5*Up**2
        F_minus = 0.5*Um**2
        Fn = 0.5*Un**2
        # U =  Un - v * (Um-Up) + a * (F_plus  * Un-Um - F_minus *Um-Up)
        U =  Un - v*(F_plus-F_minus) + a*( 0.5*(Up+U)*(F_plus-Fn)- 0.5*(U+Um)*(Fn-F_minus))
      
    else: # another implementation
        aplus[:-1] = 0.5 * (U[:-1] + U[1:])
        aplus[-1]  = 0.5 * (U[-1]  + U[0])
        aminus[1:] = aplus[:-1]
        aminus[0]   = aplus[-1]
        
        Fn[:] = 0.5*U**2
        Fplus[:-1] = Fn[1:] # or just use np.roll as you did
        Fplus[-1]  = Fn[0]
        Fminus[1:] = Fn[:-1]
        Fminus[0]  = Fn[-1]
        
        U[:] = U - dt/(2*h)*(Fplus-Fminus) + (dt**2)/(2*h**2)*(aplus*(Fplus-Fn) - aminus*(Fn-Fminus))
    
    t = t+dt
    nsteps+=1  
    
    # plot solution evolution every 10 time steps
    if np.mod(nsteps,10)==1 or t>=t_end:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x,U)
        plt.title('t={:.2f}'.format(t),fontsize=16)
        plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=18)
        plt.ylabel('u',fontsize=18)
        plt.grid()
        plt.ylim(0,1)
        plt.show()
```
````